# Drupal Wysiwig TinyMCE disappearing act

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tinymce, drupal-modules

On Drupal 7, Having installed the Wysiwig module into /opt/drupal/modules/ and TinyMCE into sites/all/libraries/ I have them more-or-less working.

The problem is as follows:

- Edit content => See the editor; everything is great
- Switch text format Full HTML => Filtered HTML and vice versa => No editor at all
- Disable rich text => see the editor (no bar) as it should be
- Enable rich text  => see the TinyMCE editor with the correct bar as it should be.

In other words, there is a glitch when switching text formats, requiring toggling rich text editing off and back on.  There are no javascript errors or anything else that indicates, drupal knows something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check wysiwyg configuration page if the TinyMCE is installed properly? Are you using a custom theme? Check if you have some css rules which causes hiding some elements provided by TinyMCE.